# How to split a with a string not on white space

Tags: java, split, whitespace, stringtokenizer

I am trying to write a code that will split a line from a text file on these characters "<" or ">". I have tried spliting with a `StringTokenizer` with those as delemiters but it still splits on spaces.
I have also used `line = file.split("(<|>)");`

Both split on spaces and i need it not to do that.

Comment: an example will be more helpful to understand

Comment: I think your ( inside your quote "(<|>" is causing the problem

Comment: i forgot to type the ) when i typed it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "123 4545>abc5  >4545454 45454 45 44555< 454545";
    String[] tokens = s.split("<|>");
    for(String t : tokens)
      System.out.println(t);
  }
```

Output:

```
123 4545
abc5  
4545454 45454 45 44555
 454545
```

Comment: my problem was my file not my split... I feel stupid now. -.-'

Comment: I feel really stupid now... I used `file.next()` not `file.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String[] split= file.split("[\\<?\\>?]");
```

Brackets ([]) denote a choice between characters.

A question mark (?) denotes a cardinality - 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

I just tried, it works fine.

```
String x = "afa f<afaf>a fa<af";
for (String s : x.split("<|>")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
afa f
afaf
a fa
af
```

Probably because in your code, you have **"(<|>"** not **"<|>"**.